# Where is the difference between c++ istream objects I create and cin and where is it visible in the library

Tags: c++

`cin` is an `istream` object.

It is created in `iostream`:

```
      /**
   *  @name Standard Stream Objects
   *
   *  The &lt;iostream&gt; header declares the eight <em>standard stream
   *  objects</em>.  For other declarations, see
   *  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/io.html
   *  and the @link iosfwd I/O forward declarations @endlink
   *
   *  They are required by default to cooperate with the global C
   *  library's @c FILE streams, and to be available during program
   *  startup and termination. For more information, see the section of the
   *  manual linked to above.
  */
  //@{
  extern istream cin;       /// Linked to standard input
  extern ostream cout;      /// Linked to standard output
  extern ostream cerr;      /// Linked to standard error (unbuffered)
  extern ostream clog;      /// Linked to standard error (buffered)

#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_WCHAR_T
  extern wistream wcin;     /// Linked to standard input
  extern wostream wcout;    /// Linked to standard output
  extern wostream wcerr;    /// Linked to standard error (unbuffered)
  extern wostream wclog;    /// Linked to standard error (buffered)
#endif
  //@}
```

I tried to create another `istream` and use it just like cin - it did not work.

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
std::istream dada;
int foo;

dada>>foo;
std::cout<<foo; 

return 0;
}
```

Because it would not compile.
I'm just looking through the library files to understand how `cin` is linked to my shell but another `istream` object is not. Can somebody explain?
I am interested in the file where the `cin` get's linked to the `STDIN` buffer.

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you edit the question and add some code?

Comment: @incBrain: Why? How would that help anyone answer the question?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley ah, I didn't read the headline, and just by reading the body it wasn't clear to me.

Comment: This has been quite messy, sorry I'm new here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::istream` is just a facade: it provides useful functions and operators, allowing you to extract numbers, arbitrary amount of characters and other things without fiddling with underlying stream, which is actually just a sequence of characters.

Actual work is done by `streambuf` object. Streams store a pointer to it and request characters from it when needed. So when you read a number from a stream, stream asks buffer for character until it find non-digit, then transforms digit characters to number.

Now to your question. Standard indeed requires `std::cin` to be of type `std::istream`, but it does not say what type its buffer is (aside from that it's derived from `std::streambuf`). Standard also does not provide such buffer for user to use, so it can be treated as *compiler magic*.

Only standard way to implement such buffer is to create your own buffer class, derived from `streambuf`, which will interact with STDIN (or cin, but it would be strange), and pass a pointer to it to `istream` constructor.

Alternatively, you can use `std::cin` own buffer:

```
std::istream my_cin(std::cin.rdbuf());
int x;
my_cin >> x;
```

Comment: Or use `std::cin.rdbuf()`

Comment: In streambuf there is no `cin` - I don't see where a line of code makes the difference between `cin` and some `std::istream` I create.

Comment: @ThomasE: Note the `extern` in the declaration of `cin`. That means it's actually defined elsewhere, in a different file. And wherever that is, it's being passed a special buffer. Either that, or it is being done in the startup code before `main`.

Comment: I'd love to see that file, any ideas?

Comment: @ThomasE: Here's the one for the the llvm implementation: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/src/iostream.cpp -- I don't know where it is in the gcc implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` is implementation of `istream` object that uses the STDIN buffer.

If you create other object, but without the buffer mapping thing, it won't work.

It is just like you try to use `ifstream` to read from file but without using the same file name.

It  similar to use `fscanf(stdin,"%s",p)` the stdin is fixed file handle, but it really some wrapper to the STDIN buffer.

Comment: More accurately, it's not the `istream` implementation, but that it gets passed a custom `streambuf` subclass.